# Accessing values from within a method

Tags: java, random, jframe

The goal of my program is to generate random centers for circles and find the length between the centers of the circles.
The issue is that in the `getd1()` method all of the values are `0` (before having 50 added, so the length ends up being 0), for `center1X`, `center1Y`, etc.

However in code I have omitted those centers are assigned to circles that are indeed drawn in random locations, so I know that the values for the center coordinates cannot be 0.

I did also try assigning values to `center1X`, etc. where they are currently initialized and I get the error that `"n must be a positive number"` which I suspect is because there is no width nor height before the `JFrame` is created. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
public class Draw extends JFrame {

    public class Circle extends JPanel {
        int center1X;
        int center1Y;
        int center2X;
        int center2Y;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Random rand = new Random();
            center1X=rand.nextInt(getWidth()-100);
            center1Y=rand.nextInt(getHeight()-100);
            center2X=rand.nextInt(getWidth()-100);
            center2Y=rand.nextInt(getHeight()-100);
            //these are coordinates of circles
        }

        public double getd1() {
            //Distance is a method that has been omitted, it functions properly and is not part of the issue
            double d1 = Distance(center1X+50,center1Y+50,center2X+50,center2Y+50);
            return d1;
        }
    }
}
```

PS: The `Distance()` function has been omitted since it is not part of the issue, but it simply uses the distance formula.

Comment: I'm missing what the actual problem is.

Comment: the problem is that inside the getd1() method the values of center1X, center1Y, center2X and center2Y are 0 and they are not 0 in the paintComponent() method. I would like to access their value inside the getd1() method